# How to get OSGI (project) created/running under IntelliJ Community/Ultimate edition(s)

Tags: intellij-idea, osgi

Delving into IntelliJ for first time. First tried the Community edition, then the Ultimate (trial). Trying to get OSGI working. The IntelliJ website shows that OSGI works on the Ultimate edition, but not on the Community edition. I can't find any feature of the freshly installed Ultimate edition that allows any OSGI projects.

I installed the "OSGI" plugin first in the Community edition, and then in the Ultimate. It doesn't seem to work in either. In both cases, after installing, there's still no option to create an "OSGI" project, nor to create a specific OSGI module/plugin. There is an OSGI item in File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | OSGI/OSGI Project Defaults that is a bare bones item that doesn't seem to do much of anything.

Unable to find any detailed instructions online online. Help me Overflow, you're my only hope.

Thanks much.

Comment: Plugin adds framework detection to existing projects. You may create new project using Maven archetype.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try that. Didn't realize i'd have to go thru yet another layer (Maven) to get it working. Is there any official documentation through the IntelliJ website to describe this (or just the Maven) process? Never used Maven. Coming back to Java after a more than a decade away. IntelliJ seems a better IDE than Eclipse, but Eclipse is-OSGI ready upon install. *sigh*

Comment: I haven't seen full tutorial, but for Maven - just create new project, select Maven and choose osgi archetype from the list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just tried it. Unfortunately, even though i've installed that "OSGi" plugin from IntelliJ, there's not even an OSGi archetype. Only: org.springframework.osgi:spring-osgi-bundle-archetype ...  was the closest i could find. I'm guessing i need some sort of Equinox or Felix archetype in Maven. If you have any more advice, greatly appreciated. Marking this as the "answer" as it seems to be pointing me in the right direction.  Cheers.